# image is getting stretched when device orientation is changed, mode is set to redraw

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimageorientation

I have a `UIImageView` embedded in a `UIScrollView`...  When the `image` is loaded the `zoom scale` is set so that the maximum amount of the `image` is visible, however when the device is rotated the aspect is not maintained and ends up appearing stretched.  Mode for views is set to `redraw`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
// get the url of the photo from flickr
NSURL* url = [FlickrFetcher urlForPhoto:self.photo format:FlickrPhotoFormatLarge];
// set the scrollview's title to be the title of the picture
self.title = [self.photo objectForKey:FLICKR_PHOTO_TITLE];
// convert the url into an image
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
// set the image as the image in the imageView
[self.imageView setImage:image];
// we will be scrolling over the size of the image
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.image.size;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
UIInterfaceOrientation currOrient = self.interfaceOrientation;
self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageView.image.size.width, self.imageView.image.size.height);
if (currOrient == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || currOrient == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    [self.scrollView setZoomScale: self.scrollView.frame.size.height / self.imageView.frame.size.height];
else {
    [self.scrollView setZoomScale: self.scrollView.frame.size.width / self.imageView.frame.size.width];

}
//     [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
// [self.scrollView setNeedsDisplay];
```

}

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
{
scrollView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller you will have to implement:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Set your zoom scale there as an animation of viewWillAppear.

Comment: great! thanks, that works wonderfully!!!  I had tried implementing    -(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration, however that didn't work, can you possibly explain to me what the difference is and why this fixed it whereas implementing the other method did not?  Thanks again!

Comment: willRotate is sent before rotation, which is used in a different situation and is meant to turn off animations and such.  Thus, no animations.  willAnimate will give new orientation info and a duration for the animation.  I think this was differentiated in iOS 3.0, which means the animations are only allowed in willAnimate.